# Performance and limitation issues between update() and batchUpdate() methods of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know when to use `update()` or `bacthUpdate()` method from `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` class of Spring framework.

Is there any row limitation for `update()`? How many rows can handle `update()` without having performance issues or hanging my db? Starting from how many rows `batchUpdate()` is getting good performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Bellow is my viewpoint:

> when to use update() or bacthUpdate() method from NamedParameterJdbcTemplate class of Spring framework

You should use `bacthUpdate()` so long as when you need to execute multiple sql together.

> Is there any row limitation for update()?

This should depends on the **DB** you use. But I haven't met row limitation for updating. Of course，updating few rows are faster than updating many rows.(such as, `UPDATE ... WHERE id=1` vs `UPDATE ... WHERE id > 1`).

> How many rows can handle update() without having performance issues or hanging my db?

This isn't sure. This depends on the **DB** you using, **Machine Performance**, etc. If you want to know the exact result, you can view the **DB Vendor's Benchmark**, or you can measure it by some tests.

> Starting from how many rows batchUpdate() is getting good performance?

In fact, `batchUpdate()` is commonly used when you do batch `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, this will improve much performance. such as:

**BATCH INSERT**:

```
SqlParameterSource[] batch = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(employees.toArray());
int[] updateCounts = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :address)", batch);
return updateCounts;
```

**BATCH UPDATE**:

```
List<Object[]> batch = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for (Actor actor : actors) {
        Object[] values = new Object[] {
                actor.getFirstName(),
                actor.getLastName(),
                actor.getId()};
        batch.add(values);
    }
    int[] updateCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
            "update t_actor set first_name = ?, last_name = ? where id = ?",
            batch);
    return updateCounts;
```

Internally, `batchUpdate()` will use `PreparedStatement.addBatch()`, you can view some [spring jdbc tutorial.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-advanced-jdbc). `Batch operations` sent to the database in one "batch", rather than sending the updates one by one.
Sending a batch of updates to the database in one go, is faster than sending them one by one, waiting for each one to finish. There is **less network traffic involved** in sending one batch of updates (only 1 round trip), and the database might be able to **execute some of the updates in parallel**. In addition, the **DB Driver** must support `batch operation` when you use `batchUpdate()` and `batchUpdate()` isn't in one transaction in default.

More details you can view:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-advanced-jdbc
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html#batch-updates-and-transactions

Hope you have to help.